# How to estimate exposure time for camera to take a good image from a scene

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, camera

I am trying to write code to calculate the correct exposure time for a camera to capture an image in correct brightness.

what I have is a camera that supply me data in RAW (Bayer raw data) and I can control its exposure time, and I want to control its exposure so when it captured an image, the image is in correct brightness (not too dark (under exposed) or too bright (over exposed).

I think I need an algorithm similar to this:

```
1-capture a sample image
2-calculate image brightness.
3-calculate correct exposure.
4-capture a new image,
5-check that the image brightness is correct if not go to step 3.
6- capture final image.
```

My question is:

1. How can I calculate image brightness?
2. If I calculate image brightness, how can I calculate exposure? One way of doing this is to do a search (for example start from very fast exposure time increase it till you get a correct exposure, but It is a very time consuming, is there any better way of doing this?)

   3. To do this, I may need to calibrate my camera (as the relationship between brightness and exposure time is different between different sensors), how can I do this?

I am using OpenCV and I can use algorithms which is available in OpenCV (c++)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to measure the "correct" brightness of the image.  A common method is to calculate the intensity histogram and make sure that the values cover the entire range of values, and there is not too much cut-off.  I'm not sure if there's a single "one fit all" way for any possible scene.

[image]

A faster way than linearly increasing the exposure is to do a binary search, by measuring at low and high exposure, then measuring in the middle, and then continuing to split the sub-range in the middle, until you find the optimum.

Comment: thanks, Some question about this method: How can I detect that the image is overexposed or underexposed by programming? Is there any algorithm in OpenCV that can help me? Is there any way that without capturing in a long exposure, I can find approximate exposure? Assume that I have a camera that can capture in 2 sec, then if I start capturing in 2 sec, the algorithm is too slow. Is there any better way? The binary search could be very slow.

Comment: Detection is simple by checking if the top/bottom X% of the histogram is not located in the edge bin (X needs tuning), but I'm not familiar with an optimized algorithm under the constraints you may have.  I'm not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: If you always work with the same camera, you may be able to pre-calculate some curve of average intensity to exposure, which would give a good starting point.  This is only speculation, though.  Needs proof.

Comment: I tried to create the curve, but the curve depend to iso (gain) and also scene   so it is not possible to define a single curve and try to find the exposure from it.